# How can I launch clean up method after stopping debugger?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have created a bunch of unit tests for my library which manipulate a certain .html file.
What I want to do is back up the file before the tests and then restore it when the tests are over. I am using the AssemblyCleanup attribute for the restoration part, which works pretty well. The only problem is that when I stop the debugger manually, the clean up code is not executed and my file is not restored...
Any advice?

Comment: I don't think there is a easy way to clean up when stopping a debugger. but I will keep an eye out on this question, I could be wrong.

Comment: Write the cleanup code so that it works without throwing exceptions even if there is nothing to clean up. Then in the setup code, first call the cleanup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't handle process termination from the process being terminated. Your only option is having another process which observes the terminated process.

Rearranging your code to do cleanup on startup would probably be a much easier option.